Why does the python version not match the banner display in juypterlab's console?
In my shell, I create a new python 3.9.19 ipykernel environment:
$ ~/local/python/3.9/bin/python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name test_3dot9
Installed kernelspec test_3dot9 in /home/user/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/test_3dot9
$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  test_3dot9    /home/user/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/test_3dot9
  python3       /home/user/local/python/3.12/share/jupyter/kernels/python3

Then I open a console with the test_3dot9 kernel in web ui of jupyterlab.
Python 3.9.19 (main, Apr 29 2024, 15:50:25) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.18.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

[1] !python --version
Python 3.12.3

Why?

! sends the command to system terminal. If python refers to version 3.12 installation on your system, that's that will be displayed with !python, regardless of what version jupyter runs on.

This is why when doing an install from within a running Jupyter notebook, you want to use %pip install or %conda install. The exclamation point often caused issues when used in conjunction with install commands and so the magic install variations were added in 2019 to insure the installations occur in the environment where the kernel backing the notebook is running. See more about the modern magic install commands here. ...

 The second paragraph here goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues.
